# Updatable ResultSet in PostgreSql9.1

Tags: jdbc, postgresql-9.1

I am working on Postgresql9.1 DB and JDBC, and want to update column value , but for doing so DB software must support updatable resultset , does 9.1 version support Updatable resultsets?

Thanks

Comment: I want to update column value in ResultSet but for doing that DB software must support Updateable ResultSets

Comment: for better and faster help edit your question

Comment: You can always use `Statement.executeUpdate()` which I find much cleaner anyway. But if you are already working with it, it will take you only a couple of minutes to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

yes it does. see ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE as Parameter of your Statements factory method.

Comment: I tried an updatable ResultSet using a select on view and was unable to edit it. Using Postgresql 9.2 jdbc jar.